# Is while in this sentence necessary?

Tags: adverbials

Today I am supposed to give my introduction in front of a student whom I am going to teach. I have prepared a speech that goes like this

> I am Kuldeep Sharma. I am a language trainer. A language trainer is someone who trains people in a specific language. I train people in English so that they are able to speak it. Being a language trainer, I am supposed to be good at the language I train people in and without being boastful, I am good at it. If I want, I can continue speaking in English or **I could train you speaking in English only (I could train you while speaking in English only)**. But I don't think that I would benefit you at all. Because you have come here to learn how to speak. You are not here to hear me speaking. So that's why for the time being, I will speak in Hindi only.

I have highlighted the problem sentence in bold. Should I use **while**?

1. I could train you while speaking in English only. Or omit it.
2. I could train you speaking in English only.

Which one of these two is correct?

I just want to say that I can provide complete training without having to resort to Hindi.

Although I have already asked a question regarding the usage of **while** but I just cannot seem to wrap my head around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think both ways are correct.

What I think besides the text:

1. You repeat yourself too much with the same ideas in a very short text.
2. You should speak in a language which your student understands. Otherwise, you will speak alone.